# LabVIEW automatic diagram clean-up fails

Tags: labview, code-cleanup

On one of my (admittedly rather complicated) VIs automatic diagram clean up has stopped working. I push the 'Clean Up Diagram' button and nothing at all happens.
I tried copying all of the code to a new VI. In the new VI the diagram clean up worked as usual. This solution would work, but it'll be a lot of work getting all the front panel decorations right and copying over the documentation etc.

I'm using LabVIEW 2013, and I don't think I'd be allowed to share my code.

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this in the original VI, or at least any idea what might be causing it?

Thanks.

Comment: If you select some part of the code, and ask for cleanup, does it work?

Comment: CharlesB, Good idea, but no. I've tried having anything from a single node to a whole structure selected with no effect.